# Eclipse 4 RCP: Is there any ways to show the Menu items of Dynamic menu contribution through a handler of Direct Tool item?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am trying to show a menu on clicking a Direct Tool item on an RCP application.

My Application.e4xmi is designed like this:

[image: My Application.e4xmi is designed like this]

I am able to display a menu using,

1. On Clicking the drop down arrow,aboutToShow() gets executed and displays the menu elements.

[image: menu elements]

```
@AboutToShow
public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items) {

    //Displays a menu when the drop down link is clicked.
}
```

2. On Clicking the area within the marked square, the execute() method of the handler attached with the direct tool item gets executed, but I am not able to get the list of MMenuElement items.

[image: marked square]

Is there any ways to display the menu elements on clicking the Handled tool item on picture 2?

Comment: The list isn't created until just before calling the @AboutToShow so it doesn't exist at all when you just click the tool item. See `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.MenuManagerShowProcessor`

Comment: @greg-449-Is it possible to use the list of MMenuElements if I invoke the AboutToShow ()once and then using it in the execute() method of Handled tool item?

Comment: I have no idea. You will have to study the source code.